# Trigger method inside UIView (Container View) from the superview

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to trigger the UIView to refresh `setNeedsDisplay` (works) but also trigger code in the SubView again, yet I can't find it anywhere. I tried to see if any view controller methods were triggered by `setNeedsDisplay`, but none do.

Any idea how to actually trigger the method of an instanced UIView in a Container View GUI element?

Comment: Assuming the subview is a custom view then you need to expose a method to trigger the code.  It's then just a case of finding the subview with the view you want to redraw and calling the method (you can use tags for that).

Comment: It's a linked UIViewController in the Storyboard. Could you further explain how I could bind it in such a way that I can trigger a method of that UIViewController (the real instance, not a new one) so I can modify data in that subview from the superview (the one im currently in)?

Comment: Can you create an *Outlet* to the subview?

Comment: It's one already :) `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *productDetailContainer;`

Comment: That looks like a generic `UIView`, not a custom view.  Is the code you want to execute part of `UIView`?

Comment: I want to click on my Product button in the Main View (CatalogViewController) and then trigger a Method inside the UIView (with UIViewController ProductDetailController). The only thing I need to do is transfer the Product ID so I can fetch it in the Container View (Product Detail) and fill the info there.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are 3 options:**

**1. Use a segue just as if you were passing data from one VC to another**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

**2. You could use NSNotificationCenter**

Post in method of your Product button's action:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"yourString" object:nil];`

Then add a listener in Main View (Catalog View Controller):

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) name:@"yourString" object:nil];`

Then trigger the action in someMethod's implementation

**3. In Catalog VC, you can use self.childViewControllers.lastObject (assuming you only have one child, otherwise use objectAtIndex:) to refer to its properties.**

`ProductDetailController *vc = (ProductDetailController *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject;`